# Spring security delegating filter proxy or Dispatcher servlet

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I am trying to understand the integration of spring MVC and hibernate providing the spring security to the web application.

My Question is If we are using Spring security in our application,then how the flow goes,is the delagating filter proxy servlet will get the user request first or its  spring dispatcher servlet ?

I am really confused how the flow goes.

Spring dispatcher servlet to delagating filter proxy ((((or)))) its the delagating filter proxy and then the dispatcher servlet.

Answer (score 0):

Genarally `filter's` are always called before `servlets`. When you have several filters and one servlet matching given `URL pattern`, `all filters are executed first in the order of <filter-mapping> definitions` and the `servlet is executed last`.

The `filter chain` reflects the order of the filters

For more specific details, [please read this](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B31017_01/web.1013/b28959/filters.htm#BCFDIHEJ)

Comment: if the authenticationmanager needs to authenticate userdetails against a database like (sql,oracle..etc) how the flow goes does it go to applicationcontext datasource bean make a connection to database and then comes back to spring-security.xml for the authentications to be done for a given username and password?????

Comment: @swethagiddaluru one question per post, please, otherwise post will say something else and internal something else.

Answer (score 0):

This part tells you that this question is related to my question's Answer regarding the flow of application context and spring security context

```
authentication-manager>
<authentication-provider>
  <jdbc-user-service data-source-ref="securityDataSource"/>
</authentication-provider>
```

> Where “securityDataSource” is the name of a DataSource bean in the application context, pointing at a database containing the standard Spring Security user data tables. Alternatively, you could configure a Spring Security JdbcDaoImpl bean and point at that using the user-service-ref attribute:

This is what i found in this link..

[spring documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/ns-config.html)

So now my question here is the flow here again changed(it is going back to applicationcontext.xml from spring-security.xml) before proceding with all  the filters.

Comment: @ankur-singhal...this is the exact question i confused with ,i got your answer ,like filters are always called before servlets.But here the spring-securtiy.xml is making a connection with database based on datasource bean in application context.xml,is it ok if the flow moves in this back and forth (i.e, from security.xml to application.xml where datasource bean is defined apart from all beans and again back to spring security to execute remaining filters like passcodeencoder.)